# How to rewrite /api/a/b/c to d.com/a/b/c in Caddy

Tags: caddy

In Caddy, I'd like to make all incoming /api/* to redirect to d.com/*.

For example `/api/a/b/c` to `d.com/a/b/c`

How to achieve this in caddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reverse proxy. Let's assume that you are listening on port 80 for all hosts, your Caddyfile would end up like this.

```
:80 {
  rewrite / {
    if {path} has api
    r /api/(.*)
    to /{1}
  }

  proxy / https://d.com/ {
    transparent
  }
}
```

Another way would be:

```
:80 {
  rewrite /api {
    r (.*)
    to /{1}
  }

  proxy / https://d.com/ {
    transparent
  }
}
```